# android - BOOT_COMPLETED is not working in android version 7.1 and below

Tags: android

I scheduled alarms and i need to reschedule it after reboot the device, it is not working in android 7.1

I have registered receiver in AndroidManifest.xml and permission but no luck. It is working correctly in android 8 and above

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<receiver android:name=".services.StartBootReceiver" android:enabled="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <actionandroid:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: It is more likely that your problem is something with the device model or manufacturer, and not with the Android OS version. `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` works in general on Android 7.1. Note that since yours is disabled (`android:enabled="false"`), it will not work unless you enable it (`setComponentEnabledSetting()` on `PackageManager`).

Comment: which device you are using?

Comment: sorry for my late response, yes seems related to device model, it is not working on Xiaomi Redmi 4X (santoni) while it is working correctly on Samsung, Nokia, Huawei. what can i do to fix it in all devices